# When Pinch zoom Textview on Android, Text are cropped unintentionally

Tags: android, textview, zooming, pinch

We developing custom textview that zoom in/out depends on pinch gesture, and able to resize textview and scale text. But, when zoom out this view, text are cropped unintentionally.

We write a code like this.

**1.Get scaled value in gesture listener and postScale in onDraw()**

**2.Calculate new view size by layout(int, int, int, int)**

```
    @Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {         

    android.graphics.Matrix m = new android.graphics.Matrix();          
    m.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);    
    canvas.concat(m);
    layout((int) l, (int) t, (int)r , (int) b );

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Comment: can you post screenshot?

Comment: Try extending the [`AutoResizeTextView`](https://code.google.com/p/a-mp-droid/source/browse/trunk/src/com/mediaportal/ampdroid/controls/AutoResizeTextView.java?r=92) by Chase Colburn.

Comment: @dd619 Sorry, I don't have a permit for upload image. But, here is a URL on screenshot. **before zoom out** http://gyazo.com/faa0cfa84fcedc5dd79941b76fc62c5e **after zoom out** http://gyazo.com/1b0e789f29c0b78200c6b39627f6dc83

Comment: @Ali Thank you for your advice. I try use this Class in my App. However, When i try to zoom in this extended TextView by pinch, text are bigger than area of view, and spill out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is may not be perfect solution for you,But you can try it.

1)Detect the pinch gesture

2)calculate the Scale factor(you can do it manually or you can use `ScaleDetector` class)

3)Use `LayoutParams` to **actually resize** your textview.

4)however it will not scale the text size but you can do it programatically respective to your scale gesture.

If you have any question feel free to comment,I have done it before with slightly different requirement.